# React-DatePicker library component Customization | Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Date Picker component from react-datepicker library. It works fine, when we click the date field, it opens the calender. Here, i want to add an down arrow inside the date field. So, when the user clicks the down arrow, it should open the calendar. Please check my code and let me know, how to add that arrow inside the date field.

Thanks in Advance.

```
class Application extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {date: moment()};
    this.dateChanged = this.dateChanged.bind(this);
  }

  dateChanged(d){
    this.setState({date: d});
  }


  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <DatePicker selected={this.state.date}
                    onChange={this.dateChanged} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Show us the code that has the dropdown please.

Comment: You are mistaken, sorry, i am not saying dropdown field, i am saying about an down arrow. Please check again, i edited. @lux

Comment: Look at the docs for custom inputs: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-43